# Implementing ADFS in asp dot net core full framework 4.6 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, runtime-error, adfs

I am trying to implement adfs authentication to a Web API dot net core that is run against the full .NET Framework using 4.6.

Using the aspnetcore.Owin library to add owin middleware to aspnetcore.

To add adfs I'm using the following code in startup.cs configure method:

```
    app.UseOwin(setup =>
        {
            var owinAppBuilder = new AppBuilder();

            owinAppBuilder.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication
            (
                new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    MetadataEndpoint = "https://claim.issuer.be/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml", // with this xml the received authorization token will be validated
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = "aaaaa", // the configured api audience name configured in ADFS
                        ValidIssuer = "https://issuer.be/adfs", // the url where adfs is located

                    }
                }
            );

            owinAppBuilder.Build<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>>();
        });
```

I get the following exception when I run the WebAPI:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Inheritance security rules violated by
>   type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either
>   match the security accessibility of the base type or be less
>   accessible.'

**UPDATE**

I fixed the exception by installing the System.Net.Http nuget package.

Now it throws an exception that no authentication handler exists.